# how can i save received image or document file from sender whatsapp using twilio?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I have a scenario like user will send the image or pdf file to twilio whatsapp number so i need to save that image/pdf in folder which will be processed to next level.

How can i save the files? I am using Node SDK.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've already configured your [webhook](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/whatsapp/api#configuring-inbound-message-webhooks) on your [sandbox page](https://www.twilio.com/console/messaging/whatsapp/sandbox), so that messages containing media from Whatsapp are getting to your app.

As [documentation says](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/twiml#twilios-request-to-your-application), you'll receive `MediaContentType{N}` and `MediaUrl{N}` as long as `body` and other parameters. The following snippet was translated-ish from a Python example from official [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/whatsapp/tutorial/send-and-receive-media-messages-whatsapp-python#save-the-media-to-the-local-file-system):

```
const Fs = require('fs')  
const Path = require('path')  
const Axios = require('axios')

const num_media = req.body.NumMedia;
const media_files = []
for (let i = 0; i <= num_media; i++) {
    const id = req.body.MessageSid
    const media_url = req.body[`MediaUrl{i}`];
    const mime_type = req.body[`MediaContentType{i}`);
    media_files.push({'media_url': media_url, 'mime_type': mime_type});

    download(media_url, id);
}

async function download(url, name) {  
  const path = Path.resolve(__dirname, 'files', name)
  const writer = Fs.createWriteStream(path)

  const response = await Axios({
    url,
    method: 'GET',
    responseType: 'stream'
  })

  response.data.pipe(writer)

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    writer.on('finish', resolve)
    writer.on('error', reject)
  })
}
```